# Find the Longest Word in a String in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error in my code

Here is the code

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let word = str.split(" ");
  console.log(word);
  let totalWords = word.length;
  for (let i = 0; i <= totalWords; i++) {
    let max = '';
    let cmax = word[i].length;
    console.log(cmax);
    if (cmax > max) {
      max = cmax;
    }
  }
  console.log(max);
}
findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

I'm confused because it showing `cmax` in console but after that giving an error.

Comment: You are looping for `word.length  + 1` times

Comment: also `max` keep outside loop

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned you are looping too far and you need to move the max outside the loop.

Also please return the value instead of console logging it in the function

Here is a neater version - note there is not a lot of input control  here

```js
const findLongestWordLength = str => str && str
  .match(/\w+/g) // find all words without spaces and punctuation
  .sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length) // sort ascending on length
  .pop()  // pop the last word
  .length; // return its length
  
console.log(
  findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
);

console.log(
  findLongestWordLength("fox")
)

console.log(
  findLongestWordLength("") // not handled
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem I faced before while learning.

The issue with the code you write, you are declaring the max variable inside the for loop, which means it will be reinitialized to an empty string on each iteration. You should move the max variable declaration outside the loop.

Also, you need to initialize the max variable to 0 instead of an empty string because you want to compare the length of the words and need to change the condition in the if statement to compare with > instead of >=.

Here is the corrected version of the code - as in the tested sentence the word "jumped" is the longest so this is giving an output of 6.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let word = str.split(" ");
  let totalWords = word.length;
  let max = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < totalWords; i++) {
    let cmax = word[i].length;

    if (cmax > max) {
      max = cmax;
    }
  }

  console.log(max);
}

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error of `Index out of Bound` which means you are looping the array more the no.of times than the length of array. It is caused here because of `i <= totalWords`. It should be `i < totalWords` only.

Also you need to define max = '' (I suggest to define it as any negative integer like `-1`) like `max=-1` outside of the loop.

```js
    function findLongestWordLength(str) {
      let word = str.split(" ");
      console.log(word);
      let totalWords = word.length;
      let max = '';
      
      for(let i = 0; i < totalWords; i++){
            
        
        
        let cmax = word[i].length;
        
        //console.log(cmax);
        
        if(cmax > max){
          max = cmax;
        }
      }
      
      console.log(max);     
      
    }

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```